# How to wait for response code 201 via curl

Tags: rest, api, asynchronous, curl, confluence

I have a curl command to publish a Atlassian Confluence space using K15t Scroll Version plugin:

```
curl -v -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST "http://<server>/rest/scroll-versions/1.0/publish/<spacekey>/to_new/publish?os_username=myusername&os_password=mypassword" --data {"versionId":"9C8CC11601610D3E794E334A746E61SD","targetSpaceKey":"pro60", "targetSpaceName":"Pro 60", "treeProviderName":"Pro 2017", "languageKey":"all", "copyLabels":"false", "keepAuthorsAndDates":"false", "removeAttachments":"false", "sendEmail":"false", "keepPermalinks":"false", "onlyPagesInFinalState":"false", "onlyPagesInFinalStateProcessChildren":"false", "publishHierarchy":"false"}
```

This command returns a response code 202 with a summary of what's happening. Then, I am required to keep checking the URL below for when the activity completes. I keep getting code 202 and finally, I get the code 201. Then, I save  the response for which I called the URL below.

```
http://<server>/rest/scroll-versions/1.0/async-tasks/<alphanumeric id generated when 202 is returned>
```

What should I do to save the response to a log file as soon it is generated after I have executed curl followed by the call to URL above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wait-for-code.sh](https://gist.github.com/romash1408/4eee10c94d8bdbd9b37f1d0dbd91461f#file-wait-for-http-code-sh) (based on https://superuser.com/a/442395/634271)

```
#/bin/sh

HOST=${1}
ATTEMPTS=${2:-10} # -1 for unlimited
CODE=${3:-200}
OUT=${4:-/dev/null}
DELAY=${5:-1s}

if [[ "$OUT" = "/dev/null" ]]; then
    GET_BODY="I"
else
    GET_BODY=""
fi

CURL="curl -${GET_BODY}so ${OUT} -w %{http_code} ${HOST}"

until [ $ATTEMPTS -eq 0 ]; do
    [ `$CURL` -eq $CODE ] && exit 0
    [ $ATTEMPTS -gt 0 ] && [ $((--ATTEMPTS)) ]
    [ $ATTEMPTS -gt 0 ] && sleep $DELAY
done

exit 1
```

Usage in your case:

```
$ SERVER="http://<server>/rest/scroll-versions/1.0/async-tasks/<alphanumeric id generated when 202 is returned>"
$ ./wait-for-http-code.sh $SERVER -1 201 out.log
```